# How will speed be affected by entity_metadata_wrapper()?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm building a big website and I'm using entity_metadata_wrapper() in lots of places around the website.

I'm wondering how this will affect the website's speed and server resources.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) does a lot of things, but most of them are cached.

For example, [entity_metadata_wrapper()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/7) calls [entity_get_info()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!includes!common.inc/function/entity_get_info/7), which uses the cache to retrieve the data. If the cache is empty, other functions are called:

```
drupal_schema_fields_sql()
cache_set()
...
```

Other modules may be involved through hooks:

```
module_invoke_all('entity_info');
drupal_alter('entity_info', $entity_info);
```

But note that no data is fetched from the database, this is because when you call entity_metadata_wrapper() you already have the entity loaded -it's a parameter to the function, indeed.

So if you are running critical or long processes such as importing data or running thousands of iterations inside a loop, you should better use entities directly. But even then, the cache should help a lot.

Look how Drupal looks without Entity API:

```
$field = '';
if (isset($entity->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE]) 
    and isset($entity->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0])) {
  $field = $entity->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
}
```

It's ugly. This is why I use Entity API almost everywhere, and I haven't had any performance issues so far. For the benefits, I think it's worth using it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is I'm not sure (I use it, but never benchmarked it). As a lighter alternative for getting and setting stuff see [field_extract](http://drupal.org/project/field_extract) which I use a lot too.